# How to call function in string on object?

Tags: javascript

I have:

```
Main.children.firstfunction.isEnabled = true;
Main.children.second.isEnabled = true;
Main.children.gsdfgsg.isEnabled = true;
Main.children.other.isEnabled = true;
```

All of these is working good, but such calls is a lot of, so I have in array:

```
var names = ['firstfunction', 'second', 'gsdfgsg', 'other'];
```

And I would like do:

```
for (var name in names) {
    Main.children.name.isEnabled = true;
}
```

But of course it does not work. How can I improve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use bracket (`[]`) notation. This will allow you to evaluate the property names dynamically.

Try

```
for (var name in names) {
   Main.children[name].isEnabled = true;
}
```